# Update database in my android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

It's been weeks I am on this problem, and i can't get to a solution. Here it is : 
When user click on an imageview, I want to update the database to add the game to "favorite". But I don't know why, it won't do. (I use a databse created with DB browser).
Here's my code :

**The update code**

```
favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             pref = "co";
             favorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             co.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             mDBHelper = new DataHelper(getApplication());
             mDBHelper.openDataBase();
             SQLiteDatabase mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

             //mDB.open();
             mDB.beginTransaction();

             ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
             values.put("pref", pref);

             //String selection = "_id" +" = '" + ID + "'";
             String[]selectionArgs = new String[1];
             selectionArgs[0] = "" + ID;

             mDB.update("tgames",
                     values,
                     "_id= ?",
                     selectionArgs);

             mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
             mDB.endTransaction();
             mDB.close();
```

**The DATA Helper code**

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_NAME = "name";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_PLACE = "place";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN = "agemin";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX = "agemax";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN = "nbremin";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX = "nbremax";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_TYPE = "type";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_PREF = "pref";
public static final String TABLE_ROW_IMG = "img";

private static final String TABLE_GAMES = "tgames";

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static String TAG = "DataHelper";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "games.db";
public static SQLiteDatabase mDB;
private final Context mContext;

File dbFile =new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

public DataHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        //DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().toString();
    }else{
        DB_PATH="/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist){
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    this.close();
    try{
        copyDataBase();
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase data base created");
    }catch (IOException mIOException){
        //throw new Error("ErroCopyingDatabase");
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    File dbFile =new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte [1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0){
        mOutPut.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutPut.flush();
    mOutPut.close();
    mInput.close();
}

public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLiteException {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    //mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDB != null;
}

public static Cursor selectAll(){
    Cursor cAll = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * from tgames", null);
    return cAll;
}

public static Cursor searchSIMPLE (String name, String place, int agemin, int agemax, int nbre, String type, String favorite){
    //A redefinir selon le critère
    //peut etre une recherche par colonne, si élément est pas null? (mais les critères s'entrecroiseront pas alors)

    String query = "SELECT * from " +
            TABLE_GAMES + " WHERE " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + " <= '" + agemin + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + " >= '" + agemax + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + " <= '" + nbre + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + " >= '" + nbre + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_PLACE + " = '" + place + "';";


    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
}

public static Cursor searchADV (String name, String place, int agemin, int agemax, int nbre, String type, String favorite){

    String query = "SELECT * from " +
            TABLE_GAMES + " WHERE " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + " <= '" + agemin + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + " >= '" + agemax + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + " <= '" + nbre + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + " >= '" + nbre + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_PLACE + " = '" + place + "' AND " +
            /*TABLE_ROW_PREF + " = '" + favorite + "'AND " +*/
            TABLE_ROW_TYPE + " = '" + type + "' ;";

    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
}

public static Cursor searchADVName (String name, String place, int agemin, int agemax, int nbre, String type, String favorite){

    String query = "SELECT * from " +
            TABLE_GAMES + " WHERE " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMIN + " <= '" + agemin + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_AGEMAX + " >= '" + agemax + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMIN + " <= '" + nbre + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_NBREMAX + " >= '" + nbre + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_PLACE + " = '" + place + "' AND " +
            TABLE_ROW_TYPE + " = '" + type + "' AND " +
            /*TABLE_ROW_PREF + " = '" + favorite + "'AND " +*/
            TABLE_ROW_NAME + " LIKE '%" + name + "%' ; ";

    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
}

public static Cursor randomMachine(){
    int cnt = getCount(selectAll());
    Random r = new Random();
    int r1 = r.nextInt(cnt)+1;
    String r2 = String.valueOf(r1);

    String sql ="SELECT * FROM tgames WHERE _id = '" + r2 + "';" ;

    Log.i("TEST", sql);

    Cursor mCur = mDB.rawQuery(sql, null);

    return mCur;
}

public static Cursor getType(String type)
{
    String sql ="SELECT * FROM tgames WHERE type = '" +type + "';";
    Cursor mCur = mDB.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return mCur;

}


private static int getCount(Cursor c){
    int cnt  = c.getCount();
    return cnt;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase mDB) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase mDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.v("TEST", "Upgrade 1");
    mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "tgames");
    try {
        createDataBase();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.v("TEST", "Upgrade FAILED");
    }
}


}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : 
I forgot, I do this operation in a child activity of main activity. When i close it, and reopen it, the initial state (favorite or not) have not changed. .

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Thats the weird part, I haven't got any error, everything go smoothly.

Comment: Show the table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the people who tried to help!
I think I found the answer : 
It was a mistake on the database create method, which was recreated each time I opened a new activity.
So I change from this :

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
if(!mDataBaseExist){
    this.getReadableDatabase();
}
this.close();
try{
    copyDataBase();
    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase data base created");
}catch (IOException mIOException){
    //throw new Error("ErroCopyingDatabase");
}
}
```

to this :

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase data base created");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            //throw new Error("ErroCopyingDatabase");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all, keep up the good work!

Answer (score -1):

you can read my code for insert new record to sqlite DB bellow:
note: i only write short code to help you know way how to insert new data to DB with some field and values.

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public void insertData(String name, String img){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TABLE_ROW_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(TABLE_ROW_IMG, img);
        //add more value here ......
        db.insert("tgames", null, contentValues);
}

}
```

so you can call insertData function whenever you want add to farvorite

Comment: I wasn't what I was expecting, but It gave me a good idea, hoping it will solve my problem :) I will go back shortly.

Comment: I don't know why some people voted down for my answer because it is short demo code to help owner's answer clear your code.